# Разная высота выделения шрифта, в разных ос

Tags: css, шрифты

в Ubuntu 16.04 в браузерах Chrome, Firefox а также на андроиде в Samsung Internet и Chrome; Шрифт подключаеться с помощью @font-face; Шрифт имеет следующую область выделения:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В Windows 7(Chrome, IE11) при выделении шрифта получаеться совсем другая высота выделения:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Буду признателен тем кто объяснит в чем дело. Спасибо.

Comment: Дело все в шрифте и его корявости восприятия

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема в том как ОС рендерит каждый шрифт.

Варианты решения проблемы:

1. **Найдите замену шрифту:**
   Как правило топовые шрифты проработаны и не имеют проблем с кроссплатформеностью.
2. **Попробуйте [этот](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator) сервис:**
   Данный сервис унифицирует Ваш шрифт и возможно это решит проблему.

более детально про шрифты и их жизненный цикл в вебе можно почитать [здесь](https://pikabu.ru/story/frontend__optimizatsiya__shriftyi__rendering_5638170)